# BigQuery Join Tables

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Example, I have 2 tables.

Pet

| PetID | PetName | PetType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Charlie | Dog |
| 456 | Rose | Cat |
| 789 | Sam | Rabbit |

Owner

| PetID | OwnerName | OwnerNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Phil | 1234567 |
| 123 | Carly | 2345678 |
| 456 | Russel | 3456789 |
| 456 | Sophie | 4567891 |
| 789 | Tasha | 5678912 |
| 890 | Bill | 6789012 |
| 901 | Shay | 7890123 |

I want the result to be:

| PetID | OwnerName | OwnerNumber | PetName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Phil | 1234567 | Charlie |
| 456 | Russel | 3456789 | Rose |
| 789 | Tasha | 5678912 | Sam |

I only want the PetId's that are in Pet. I only want distinct PetId's. How would I go about this in BigQuery? Inner Join?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go with

```
select o.*, PetName
from owner o
join pet p
using (PetID)
where true 
qualify row_number() over(partition by PetID) = 1
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple `join` but you have to restrict to a single pet id.  You can use `qualify`:

```
select p.*, o.ownernumber
from pet p join
     owner o
     using (petid)
where 1=1
qualify row_number() over (partition by petid order by petid) = 1;
```

You can use the `order by` to control which owner you get.